# MySQL query with empty WHERE - index optimization

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

For an index page of an app I need to pull all entries from a table from MySQL-DB. It is possible to set filters, but initially the where-clause is `WHERE 1=1`. While that returns the expected results an `EXPLAIN` shows, that no index is used, so the query is pretty slow.

What's the best way of solving this?

---

EDIT:

this is the query

```
SELECT 
    `Module`.`id`, 
    `Module`.`name`, 
    `Module`.`module_class_id`, 
    `Module`.`editor`, 
    `ModuleClass`.`name`, 
    `Editor`.`name`, 
    `ModuleClass`.`id`, 
    `Editor`.`id`, 
    `Mc`.`id` 
FROM `Module` 
LEFT JOIN `ModuleClass` ON (`Module`.`module_class_id` = `ModuleClass`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `Editor` ON (`Module`.`editor` = `Editor`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `Mc` ON (`Module`.`id` = `Mc`.`module_id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY `Module`.`id` 
ORDER BY 
    `Module`.`id` DESC, 
    `ModuleClass`.`name` ASC, 
    `Editor`.`name` ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

and this is the result of the explain:
[image: screenshot of explain query]

and yes: I do understand that it does not make too much sense that the db is using an index here, but since this seems to be a rather common case to me I hoped there was a best practice to face the issue

Comment: Don't use any kind of `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If you have no filter (or just `WHERE 1=1`, it's the same), the whole table has to be returned. Why should an index be used?

Comment: I don't get it, do you think if you add indexes that entire database just magically gets faster? You have no WHERE, ergo you get the whole table. How in the world can you make that operation faster by using indexes is against any common sense.

Comment: @ypercube unless the rows must be sorted (but the OP hasn't said anything about this)

Comment: @MarcelloRomani Even with sorting, indexes may not be worth using. But you are correct, the OP has not provided an actual query. He may have `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT`. Who knows...

Comment: Please see the edit in the question. I get the point, but then how would you create that type of query for large result sets of >1M ?

Comment: Remove the `ORDER BY` completely and use `GROUP BY Module.id DESC`

Comment: Thanks. That has the same effect as removing `ORDER BY ModuleClass.name, Editor.name` -> so improving the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index in the order by clause. So if ID is your primary_index then write `WHERE 1=1 order by ID`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do have an ORDER BY for the primary id included. The query improves when I remove the extra ORDER BY clauses, so your hint helped me